# Longest journey by a Federation vessel?

Tags: star-trek

I am curious about which Federation crew has had the longest, uninterrupted mission/journey without direct Starfleet support (repairs, re-supply, personnel rotations, etc).

Any era of Trek is acceptable, but I am looking for the longest journey experienced by a crew, so hopping into the future through a wormhole wouldn't count. I will consider answers where the crew survived, but their ship did not (crash landings, abandoned ships, etc).

The number to beat: an alternate timeline Enterprise NX-01 became a generation ship, traveling for about 117 years.

Comment: I can't find the 117 year journey you are referring to.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz That would be the 'Enterprise' episode 'E²' (s3e21). The Enterprise time travels to 2037 and sticks around in the Expanse until 2154 to help the about-to-time-travel Enterprise.

Comment: in time or space? Books as well or just tv/film?

Comment: @NKCampbell I would say "time relative to the crew", So getting suddenly thrown through time, no matter how far, is still only a few seconds or minutes "on the clock", for my purposes. To be honest I'm not very familiar with the status of the books, but if it comes from a solidly canon source, I'll definitively accept it.

Comment: In that case, the Star Trek Destiny trilogy may qualify. The NX-02 Columbia gets thrown back millions of years and 'survive' to the 24th century. To say anymore would spoil a terrific series.

Comment: @NKCampbell To qualify for an accepted answer you will have to give more details. And spoilers. :-) You say the Columbia survives. But are there descendants of the crew who have a continuing memory of the original journey?

Comment: @NKCampbell As far as I can tell from MemoryBeta (which is not canon), the NX-02 is thrown back to the 16th century; the ship thrown back millions of years is a Caeliar ship. But Erika Hernandez, captain of the *Columbia*, does survive in linear time to the 24th century. But from what I can tell from the books' synopses she sort of gives up on whatever her mission was supposed to be very quickly (and after being made immortal by the Caeliar). She only tries to escape after meeting up with Riker in the late 24th century.

Comment: Not sure if it qualifies, but there is Data's mission where he is transported the 1800s? saves Picard and Guinan, loses his head and then his head is found in the 2300s, His head ages and must have some sort of clock ticking in there and the whole is 500 years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**200 Years**

In Deep Space Nine's '[Children of Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_Time_(episode))' (s5e22) the crew of the *Defiant* is thrown back in time 200 years and their 8000 descendants (and Odo and Dax) survive to meet up with the *Defiant* again.

Comment: wouldn't the journies in both First Contact (film), City on the Edge of Forever (TOS) and Tomorrow is Yesterday (TOS) be longer than 200 years and without "direct" orders? Tomorrow is Yesterday and City on the Edge were both due to accidents and Picard makes the choice on his own (even possibly violating orders just being in that sector) to follow the Borg. Also - re-reading looks like the OP is asking for physical distance, not time

Comment: That is not a "journey on a Federation vessel".   That is just a bunch of people who colonized in the past.   -1

Comment: @ThePopMachine According to the last sentence of the second paragraph of the original question this "mission" does qualify. Crash landing, continuing survival.

Comment: @Hans:  Survival is not a mission.   It's more of a standing order if it's anything.

Comment: @NKCampbell Those missions were in the past but didn't last that long. In *First Contact* they went back 300 years but the entire mission lasted only several days.

Comment: @ThePopMachine The example given by VapedCrusader, the NX-01 Enterprise being thrown back in time 117 years, is exactly the same. The (decendants of the) people experiencing the time paradox are waiting for the original moment the timeshift happened to make sure the same thing does not happen (Enterprise) or does happen (Defiant). It's a mission of a sort. Self-imposed, but still a mission.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 "debatable" answers to this...

the first is "The Voth" in general left Earth 75 million years ago and might actually qualify as federation citizens which means their journey is the longest on record.

The second is "Voyager" depending on how you see the backup EMH program. If you view him as a separate entity from the Doctor, he certainly is part of the Federation and his trip lasted 700 to 900 years if he actually got home... although that's relative, considering he spent most of that time in active memory deactivated. And the other problem is the rest of voyager made it home at least 600 years prior to him being reactivated.

Comment: I don't see how the Voth "might qualify as Federation citizens" and I don't see how the backup EMH counts as "journey by a Federation vessel".   No on both.   -1

Comment: @ThePopMachine If you interpret the question as "What crew/vessel and their descendant left earth and spent the most amount of time away before returning" which it can be interpretted as the Voth left Earth and have yet to return. The Back-up EMH is literally a part of Voyager and a crew member as much as the Doctor is.

Comment: You're bending over backwards to get your answer to fit the question.   That's just not what the question is.   The question is "longest uninterrupted journey/mission by a Federation vessel".   It is quite clear.   There are essentially three elements you are ignoring to various degrees:  **journey/mission**, **Federation**, and **vessel**.

Comment: @ThePopMachine The Voth one, maybe, but the back-up EMH qualifies as all 3 definitely..

Comment: How do you get that?   back-up EMH is Federation.   That is one out of three.   He is not really on a journey or mission for 800 years, nor is he a vessel or on one.

Comment: @ThePopMachine He's ultimately on a Journey back to Earth, started with Voyager's crew and ended separated from it. Just because his journey has him lying dormant doesn't mean he wasn't on that journey during that period. Likewise he is literally part of Voyager which makes anywhere he goes "on a vessel" however weird that sounds.

Comment: @Durakken The one big point (to me) where the backup EMH fails the conditions set is the "uninterrupted" part. Almost all of the time the EMH was dormant and you have to look at it from the EMH's point of view. VapedCrusader also mentioned this (4th comment in original question): "on the clock". The backup EMH was not "on the clock" for 800 years.

Comment: @Durakken I think the Voth don't qualify because they don't have a persisting memory of their "mission". Also, if they have a mission at all it is not to get back to Earth.

Comment: @Hans I think at best, you could say he's not on the clock so long as he's deactivated, but while he is activated that should count. We're told that he served as their head of Medicine for a long time If we assume it takes him quite a while to get to that position and then to get a ship that he thinks is reliable and then assume it takes him a similar amount of time to get to Earth as it would without trans-warp then the time it takes him to get home has to be in the 200ish year range.

Comment: @Durakken The problem is that in *Living Witness* no duration is given for the backup EMH's service. The trip back would be in the decades at 24th century technology level. But when the backup EMH is reactivated it's the 32nd century so his trip back could very wel be shorter (in time) because of better technology. Either way, there is no way to determine how long the backup EMH was active before he reached Earth again. (Or even if he got back at all.)

Comment: @Hans True on not knowing the length of the trip, but given the average level of technology advancement and comparison between the 3 time periods we are given we can be fairly sure that the tech level of the people the doctor is dealing with is more advanced than the federation in terms of ship speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the longest Starfleet journey by distance, it would be the episode involving [The Traveler](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Traveler).

To summarize: The Traveler is a mysterious being who, through the power of pure thought, helps focus the Enterprise's warp core.  In their mission to 'test this enhancement', they first are launched to the M33 galaxy.  In a panic to get home, they then overshoot the mark and travel a billion more lightyears to the 'end of the universe'.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Like the rest of the network we are a Q/A site and not a discussion forum so I've edited out the "discussiony" part of your answer.